# Database Full Backup fails being deadlock victim

Tags: sql-server, backup, deadlock

On one of my SQL Server 2008 R2 Databases, Full backup job fails about twice a month due to Deadlocks. Transaction Log backup is only other job which is scheduled to execute at the same time. 
Can you help me investigate what causes deadlock on backup operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server backup operations do not acquire locks, see - [Paul Randal's post](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-3030-backup-myths/).
Therefore `BACKUP DATABASE...` or `BACKUP LOG...` cannot become deadlock victims.

Probably some other queries that take part in your backup jobs take part in deadlocks.

If you can describe your backup solution in detail, we might be able to help you.

I personally recommend [Ola Hallengren's backup solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/) to do the job.